# Why was this edit approved?

Tags: discussion, editing

I don't really understand why this edit was approved:
https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5764

I think it makes the question impossible to answer because it removes the link and it clearly vandalises the intent of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was the approver.  I goofed up, clearly missed the obvious.  "Should have gone to Specsavers" as the UK advert for budget reading glasses firm Specsavers has it.